# Cant access site using IE and Edge

Tags: content-migration

I juts migrated the SP from 2010 and 2013 using content database migration. My site has a dns entry and also configured access mapping. The issue is the sites wont open with IE and edge, keep asking for my user/pass. However Chrome is fine.

Can you please help?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Since SharePoint site would use the desktop credentials in case you are opening it in IE.

Try this Goto Tools> Internet Options> Security> Select the zone in which your site lies> Custom Level

Scroll down in user authentication select Prompt for Username and Password. > Apply

Close the browser and restart and try accessing the site again which will give you a prompt this time to enter yor windows credentials.

Same issue that was faced and mentioned [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/55ec4a36-8b7a-4333-b8c6-11b30ac645fe/sharepoint-2013-cannot-access-through-ie?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: the issue was I didnt set up SPN properly in domain controller. (Service Principle Name)

Comment: glad to hear that you resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Need to update Service Principle Controller in Active directory.